# TypeError: props.routes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react-redux. I am trying to pull data from Asp.Net Core Web Api to my react project.

I get an error when mapping the data I receive with redux in react.

I see the data coming in redux DevTools. State is filling up.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as actions from "../redux/actions/routeActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function Data({ ...props }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchRoutes();
  });

    function renderData() {
        return props.routes.map((route) => {
            const { id, departureLocation, arrivalLocation, distance } = route
            return (
                <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{id}</td>
                    <td>{departureLocation}</td>
                    <td>{arrivalLocation}</td>
                    <td>{distance}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
    return(
        < div >
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th />
                        <th>departureLocation</th>
                        <th>arrivalLocation</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {renderData()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div >
    );
}

Data.propTypes = {
    routes: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  routes: state.routes,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchRoutes: actions.fetchAll,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(Data);
```

And i get this error.

```
TypeError: props.routes.map is not a function.
```

I couldn't find where I made a mistake.

Comment: You need to initialize `routes` as an empty array i.e. `[]`. The error means `routes` was an object the moment it tried to call `map` on it. So, you probably need to fix that in your reducer.

Comment: On a very basic level, `props.routes.map is not a function` means that `props.routes` is not an array. Given your propTypes setup, passing a non-array as routes prop should cause a warning the browser's console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because routes are not ready on first render.

Rendering with condition will ensure that you dont map into routes that does not exist.

```html
<tbody>
  {props.routes && props.renderData()}
</tbody>
```

Better solution would be setting your routes initial value in reducer of redux as an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers you can also make your renderData to handle routes more safe like this :

```js
    function renderData() {
        return (props.routes || []).map((route) => {
            const { id, departureLocation, arrivalLocation, distance } = route
            return (
                <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{id}</td>
                    <td>{departureLocation}</td>
                    <td>{arrivalLocation}</td>
                    <td>{distance}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful as you are fetching your routes in an `effect` without dependencies.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  props.fetchRoutes();
});
```

This might enter an infinite loop as you are fetching routes every time your component re-renders.

To ensure that does not happen add a `dependency` to the `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  props.fetchRoutes();
}, [props.fetchRoutes]);
```

This will only enter the `useEffect` *(besides the first render)* whenever the `fetchRoutes` variables changes, which should once at a maximum. You could use `[]` to do it like it was `ComponentDidMount`. If you're using react hooks eslint it won't let you without a warning though. [You can read more about the useEffect hook here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

Regarding the `not a function` part, the reason is likely to be that your data still isn't there when the first render happens *(as you still need to fetch your data)* and therefore it will try to do a `map` of an `undefined`.

As said in other comments one option is to only map through the variable if the variable has any value. The other would be to [`destructure`](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0) your props and default the variable to `[]`.

```js
function Data({ fetchRoutes, routes = [] }) {
  ...
}
```

This way you also won't need the `props.` part.